# SQL..Write a query to match on name and dob from one table to find record in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, rstudio

I have two tables with customer demographics. There is no primary key. The only way I have to match up records is with first name, last name, and dob. I've never had to match records without a primary key. How can I write a query to pull records with same lastname, firstname, and dob?

Comment: Show us some data and maybe someone can help you.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166) (ignore if you're not asking about hw). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Why do you think matching on these columns is any different from matching records by primary key?

Comment: @Barmar I'm thinking that perhaps the reason for the lack of primary keys is that there are not any exact matches.  Hence, we might have to use `LIKE` or something similar.  Anyway, without data we can't give an answer here.

Comment: @SHELL The trouble with what you've got going on is that you can never guarantee that the two tables will always match up on just those 3 pieces of information. If one or the other was incorrectly inserted, it becomes an orphan until another miss-typed entry occurs in the other table. If you're talking demographics, the name doesn't matter all that much right? You are probably after some other data in the table. If keeping this configuration is your only option, I'd recommend joining on more than just name and DOB, its just not specific enough with a large set of data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Join on all three columns if the format of data is same in both the tables . Like (Date Format etc ..) or help us by showing some data .

Comment: I'm kind of new at this and not sure how to add a file but here is some data from joining both tables on the first and last name. I need to match on DOB because right now, that field is not matching. I tried Brein's formual but I got an error.

Comment: CLAIM_ID PRIMARY_KEY_VALUE RECORD_ID         
                                                                                                
           LAST_NAME FIRST_NAME DATE_OF_BIRTH BRTH_DT
1706116946 9583589 1 Johnson James 19611118 4/28/1957
1710332672 9583589 1 Johnson James 19611118 4/28/1957
1705998240 9583589 1 Johnson James 19611118 4/28/1957
1710537274 9583589 1 Johnson James 19611118 4/28/1957